# Is gravity lost or gained by applying energy?

Tags: forces, energy, mass

### Is gravity lost or gained by applying energy?

Background:

1. When I hold an apple with my outstretched hand, I use energy to keep it from falling.
2. When I drop an apple (or throw it down), it looses potential energy.

Where does the energy go?

Is gravity gained or lost? (The farther you are away from something, the less the gravity between the two objects. The closer you are to something, the greater the gravity.)

Does dropping something increase gravity, and holding something decrease gravity, and if so by how much?

The energy I use to hold the apple must go somewhere. Does it go into decreasing the gravity between my apple and the center of gravity?

How much of earth's gravity is gained or lost? What does that say about very large and very small cases?

The mass does not change, but does the real feel gravity change?

Is it easier to lift something once it has been lifted? Is it harder to lift something that was thrown down?

Question 1: *How much of earth's gravity is lost while I'm holding the apple for one second?*
Question 2: *How much of earth's gravity is gained when I drop the apple for one foot or one meter, and it hits the ground?*

Comment: one force can act in opposition to another - but work is only done when a force moves through a distance. When work is done energy is transferred. You can put an apple on a table and it resists gravity - no work is done. Holding you arm out you are using energy to sustain muscle tension, but if you had inflexible wire instead that would be unnecessary.

Comment: You sound like you're ready for an introductory text on Physics. I highly recommend Paut Hewitt's Conceptual Physics.

Comment: Re *when I hold an apple with my outstretched hand, I use energy to keep it from falling.*-- Yes, you do, but this has nothing to do with gravity changing. It instead has to do with the complexities of the human muscular and skeletal systems. Take a break and set the apple on the table. The table burns zero energy keeping the apple from falling to the floor.

Answer (score 1):

In Newtonian terms, sufficient for this conversation, gravity is a force that exists between two objects due to their masses. The strength of this force is proportional to the mass of each object and inversely proportional to the square of the distance between them. The magnitude of the force between the apple and the earth will change somewhat as you raise and lower the apple but no one speaks of gravity as being "lost".

Since the distance between the objects is measured from their center of mass, and the center of the earth is 4,000 miles below you, the force between the apple and the earth is virtually the same whether the apple is 6 feet in the air or resting on the ground.

Work occurs when a force acts to move an object over a distance. Energy is the "ability to do work". Since the apple is not moving as you hold it seationary, no energy is expended from a *purely physics perspective*. Of course your muscles are twitching a bit and there is all sorts of molecular motion in your body that requires energy but that is typically beyond the domain of pure physics as seems the intent of your question. If the apple were placed on a shelf holding it above the earth, no energy would be expended at all.

If you drop the apple, the earth will then be allowed to exert a gravitational force that will do work on the apple by actually moving it. In physics terms, the gravitational energy the apple had due to its position relative to the earth will be converted to energy of motion, kinetic energy, as the apple accelerates downward. When the apple strikes the earth, the apple will deform slightly as will the earth beneath it. The molecules in both will be scrunched around a bit and both the apple and earth will become just a tad warmer. Rub your hands together briskley to feel this effect. So the kinetic energy achieved during the apple's fall ultimately ends up a thermal energy, the energy of motion of the particles within a substance. Some of that thermal energy will also warm the surrounding air, we call this transfer of thermal energy heat.